# How to include and properly use @types/cytoscape UI extension in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, angular7

I'm trying to include grid-guide and edgehandles cytoscape.js extensions into my Angular7 project. It works, but not as intended (I think), I can't disable drawing edgehandles when it is initialized, but not started.

cytoscape is imported with the @types/cytoscape

Grid-guide: https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-grid-guide
edgehandles: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles

The extensions are currently imported through npm

I've tried to follow this issue posted, but it didn't get me far: [How to use UI extension for Cytoscape.js in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449399/how-to-use-ui-extension-for-cytoscape-js-in-typescript)

I've tried using a custom typings.d.ts file, which is recommened by the @types/cytoscape (see the bottom of index.d.ts file)

```
typings.d.ts:
declare module 'edgehandles-cyto' {
  const ext: cytoscape.Ext;
  export = ext;
};

And importing into the component:
import cytoscape = require('cytoscape'); //This works


//Importing jquery and grid-guide, works, but maybe not as intended
var jquery = require('jquery');
var gridGuide = require('cytoscape-grid-guide');

//Importing cytoscape extension, edgehandles, works, but not as intended
var edgehandles = require('cytoscape-edgehandles');

//Connected with cytoscape
gridGuide( cytoscape, jquery );
cytoscape.use(edgehandles);

//After cytoscape is initialized, trying to include these extensions
this.cy.gridGuide(options);    //Options and defaults are already set
this.cy.edgehandles(defaults);
```

Link to project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cytoscape

Expected result would be to start edgehandles with this.cy.edgehandles('drawon');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake by me, but if anyone is struggling with it. All you need to do is to use:
'''
//set a variable for the extension:
public eh:any;

....

this.eh = this.cy.edgehandles(defaults);
this.eh.disable(); //instead of this.cy.edgehandles('drawon');
'''

Answer (score 2):

I used Angular CLI 7.x to generate a project and use the extension succesfully:

Cytoscape gives some information in "index.d.ts" file under ./node-modules/@types/cytoscape at the end of the file which should work for all extensions.

I am writing all steps below that I used to make 'cytoscape-panzoom' extension work. you can use the same steps for any other extension.

1. Install cytoscape using `npm install cytoscape`
2. Install cytoscape types using `npm install --save @types/cytoscape`
3. Install the root types `npm install @types/node --save-dev` (You may use --save see npm guide)
4. Make sure your tsconfig.json file has the following, otherwise
   add it (this is needed for 'require(...)' to work):

   ```
   "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ]
   ```
5. Install the cytoscape extension using 'npm install cytscape-panzoom'
   (in your case your extension name inplace of "cytoscape-panzoom", check the github for the extension you are using)
6. Add the  javascript and style files of the cytoscape extension; .js and .css (if applicable) to the relevant sections inside your 'angular.json' file:

   "styles": ["src/styles.css","./node_modules/cytoscape-panzoom/cytoscape.js-panzoom.css"],
   "scripts": ["./node_modules/cytoscape-panzoom/cytoscape-panzoom.js"]
7. Create a file in the root of your Angular project with an
   extension *.d.ts, in my case I used 'panzoom.d.ts' you can use the
   name of your cytoscape extension or simply typings.d.ts.
8. Put the following code in your .d.ts file and in place of
   "cytoscape-panzoom" you can use your extension's name:

   ```
       declare module 'cytoscape-panzoom' {
       const ext: cytoscape.Ext;
       export = ext;
     }
   ```
9. within the component write the following import code:

   ```
   var cyt = require ('cytoscape');
   var pz = require('cytoscape-panzoom');
   cyt.use(pz);
   ```

Now you can use the extension!

Usage sample:

```
...............

let cy_contianer = this.renderer.selectRootElement("#cy");
let cy = cyt({
container: cy_contianer,
layout: this.layout,
elements: this.elements,
minZoom: 0.3,
maxZoom: 5
});

  cy.style(this.style);

 var defaults = {
      zoomFactor: 0.05, // zoom factor per zoom tick
      zoomDelay: 45, // how many ms between zoom ticks       
      zoomInIcon: 'fa fa-plus',
      zoomOutIcon: 'fa fa-minus',
      resetIcon: 'fa fa-expand'

 // .... more settings here removed to make it short for sample
    };

    // HERE WE ARE USING THE EXTENSION THROUGH THE SAME cy OBJECT RETURNED BY cytoscape(..) function. 

    cy.panzoom(defaults);
```

Hope the answer helps.