# What does the "as" keyword do?

Tags: typescript

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    (WithUser as any).displayName = wrapDisplayName(Component, 'withUser');
}
```

I'm not even sure if `as` is a keyword, but anyway, what does it do in JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any difference between type assertions and the newer \`as\` operator in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503077/any-difference-between-type-assertions-and-the-newer-as-operator-in-typescript)

Comment: 'as' is type assertion expression used in Typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript. what is mean: (this as any)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551681/typescript-what-is-mean-this-as-any)

Answer (score 302, accepted):

That is not vanilla JavaScript, it is TypeScript. `as any` tells the compiler to consider the typed object as a plain untyped JavaScript object.

The `as` keyword is a [Type Assertion in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) which tells the compiler to consider the object as another type than the type the compiler infers the object to be.

Comment: Please tell what `as` does if the asseration fail. Will a error or exception be thrown?

Comment: Nothing. It is purely a compiler concept to tell the compiler to consider an object a different type than it infers. The compiled JavaScript that actually runs has no concept of types. The code that runs will throw errors and exception based on the compiled JavaScript.

Comment: Could you please link any TypeScript documentation you referred to or that can support this answer?

Comment: Sometimes this "as" is only solution in ts apps,when some object havent exact type.

Comment: Documentation about `as` https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion

Comment: I've edited the answer to add an official link

Comment: Note that `as` can also be used in another (more complex) context in typescript: `type CapitalizeKeys<T> = {[key in keyof T as (key extends string ? Capitalize<key & string> : key)]: T[key]}`. I'm afraid I haven't been able to determine the exact semantics of `as` in this context.

Comment: I have an error during compilation when I use 'as' in my .tsx file

Answer (score 56):

It's TypeScript, not vanilla JS, but for the `as` itself: It's called **Type Assertion**, you are just telling the compiler to treat something as a type:

```
var a = 'TEST STRING'
var b = a as string; //Means the compiler will assume it's a string
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
var a = 'TEST STRING'
var b = <string> a;
```

However it might be confusing when working with JSX (JS with html tags)
, so in those cases the `as` syntax is preferred.

Comment: is there any difference between
var b = 'test' as string; and var b: string = 'test' ?

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs to answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220403/is-there-a-difference-between-as-type-operator-and-classical-typing-in-typescr?noredirect=1#comment122344292_69220403

Answer (score 16):

This is a Typescript operator, it's not available in ECMAScript 2015 (latest release of Javascript)

As the answers above indicated, the 'as' operator is a form of **Type Assertion**

To take a short example, say you have two types: First & Second. You're writing a method, and the method doesn't exactly know which type your object will be of. It could be of type First or Second.

So, you declare your variable without a strict type. Once your method is aware of the type your variable should take on, you can return it 'as that type'.

That seemed a little vague and ambiguous, but the 'as' operator actually performs the exact same function as another (more familiar) pattern:

These two snippets of code *do the exact same thing*

```
    let accountCode = '123';
    let castedAccountCode = <number>accountCode;
```

Using as keyword:

```
    let accountCode = '123';
    let castedAccountCode = accountCode as number;
```

Comment: This code generates: TS2352: Conversion of type 'string' to type 'number' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Comment: If you know you want a number from a string then why not to write this instead?   const accountCode = '123';
  const castedAccountCode: number = parseInt(accountCode, 10);

Comment: Or simply: const castedAccountCode: number = +accountCode;

Answer (score 11):

This kind of type assertion is useless, as

```
function foo (a: string, b: string): number {
    return (a as number) + (b as number)
}
```

simply transpiles to

```
function foo(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I first expected it to be something like

```
function foo(a, b) {
    if (typeof a != 'string') throw ...
    if (typeof b != 'string') throw ...
    return Number(a) + Number(b)
}
```

but no. TS gives users a wrong sense of security.

Comment: That's probably because the operator + is also valid for string, if you change 'string' for 'boolean' at the signature, the resulting code is the same, but you will have a compiler error.

Comment: Once you understand what the point of 'as' is, then there really isn't a "wrong sense of security."

Comment: `as` is used to help typescript check types at compile time, not for type coercion at runtime.

Comment: @ABOS i was expecting that first code snippet meant third one !!! i am not able to understand what your comment meant to say !!!

Comment: That’s just how Typescript works. You need to understand the difference between type space and value space in typescript to truly understand the behavior of “as”.

Answer (score 6):

### Key Mapping via `as`

In the provided example of the OP the `as` keyword is used for [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). In TypeScript 4.1 and onwards the `as` keyword can not only be used for [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) but also for [Key Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).
This allows you to re-map the keys of a type. E.g.:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

type Getters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as `get${Capitalize<K & string>}`]: () => T[K];
};

type MappedPerson = Getters<Person>;

// type MappedPerson = {
//   getName: () => string;
//   getAge: () => number;
// }
```

---

Generic & [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) really shine here. [Key Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) is a very mighty feature because you can also map a key to the type of it's value. For instance, with the help of [Conditional Types](https://4) it's possible to *filter* object properties by the type of a key's corresponding value . Let's say we want to remove all properties of type `number` on the `Person` type:

```
type WithoutPropertiesOfTypeNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends number ? never : K]: T[K];
};

type PersonWithoutPropertiesOfTypeNumbers =
  WithoutPropertiesOfTypeNumber<Person>;

// type PersonWithoutPropertiesOfTypeNumbers = {
//     name: string;
// }
```

Answer (score 4):

as above answers pointed the word `as` in the code of the original question is a keyword in TypeScript, however as a supplement, `as` is contextual keyword in JavaScript - when the code runs into the syntax rule [ImportClause](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-ImportClause)

Answer (score 4):

In TypeScript, the `as` keyword is used to explicitly type cast a value to a different type. It allows you to tell the TypeScript compiler that you know more about the type of a value than it does, and to treat that value as if it were of a different type.

For example, consider the following code:

```
let myValue: any = "Hello, world!";
let myLength: number = (<string>myValue).length;
```

In this code, `myValue` is of type `any`, which means that TypeScript doesn't know anything about its type. We can use the `as` keyword to tell TypeScript that we know `myValue` is a `string`, like this:

```
let myValue: any = "Hello, world!";
let myLength: number = (myValue as string).length;
```

Both examples achieve the same result, but the second example uses the `as` keyword to perform the type cast.

Note that when using the `as` keyword, you are telling TypeScript that you are sure of the type of the value. If you make a mistake and cast a value to the wrong type, it can cause runtime errors. Therefore, it's important to be careful when using the `as` keyword and make sure that you're casting to the correct type.