# TypeGraphql and Prisma 2 type conflicts

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, typegraphql

I am using TypeGraphql and Prisma 2 on an Apollo Express server with a PostgreSQL db.

I used Prisma to introspect my DB and then generated the TypeScript types from `schema.prisma`.

I also have my `@ObjectType` model classes made with TypeGraphQL.

My issue is that I seem to be running into type conflicts between my TypeGraphQL classes and the generated types from Prisma. For example I have a TypeGraphQL `Course` class that looks like this

```
@ObjectType()
export class Course {
  @Field(() => Int)
  id: number;

  @Field()
  title: string;
  .......

  @Field(() => User)
  creator: User;
}
```

and Prisma generates a `Course` type that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Model Course
 */

export type Course = {
  id: number
  title: string
  .......
  creator_id: number
}
```

So in my custom resolvers, when I try to create a `Course`, I say that the mutation returns a type of `Course`. (I have a controller using this service but the service is where the issue is)

```
export const createCourseService = async (
  prisma: PrismaClient,
  createCourseInput: CreateCourseInput,
  userId: number
): Promise<Course> => {
  let err, newCourse, foundUser;
  const { course, user } = prisma;

  .....

  [err, newCourse] = await to(
    course.create({
      data: {
        ...createCourseInput,
        creator: {
          connect: { id: userId },
        },
      },
    })
  );
  return newCourse;
};
```

But the `Course` type that comes from my TypeGraphQL class is different from the `Course` type generated by Prisma but they're named the same so TypeScript sort of thinks they're the same but gives and error saying that creator is missing in type `Course` but required in type `Course`. Not really sure what the best way to resolve this is.

Is there some way to stitch my TypeGraphQL classes and my Prisma types together or go about it some other way?

Comment: You can have two conflicting definitions for a type as long as you aren't using them in the same file.  In the file where you are declaring `createCourseService`, make sure that you import `Course` from the file with the class `Course`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste that's what I'm doing. The class Course is what's marked as the return type for createCourseService but prisma.course.create() returns a Course type that is the type that prisma generates and so those two types conflict with each other

Answer (score 2):

When importing the types, you can use [`as` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do) (doing a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)) and rename one of the types. You could e.g. rename the `Course` from Prisma to `PrismaCourse`, `DBCourse` or `CourseModel` or anything else you prefer. Here's the syntax to use for that:

```
import { Course as DBCourse } from '@prisma/client'
```

Then, in your resolver you can have the following code:

```
export const createCourseService = async (
  prisma: PrismaClient,
  createCourseInput: CreateCourseInput,
  userId: number
): Promise<DBCourse> => {
  let err, newCourse, foundUser;
  const { course, user } = prisma;

  .....

  [err, newCourse] = await to(
    course.create({
      data: {
        ...createCourseInput,
        creator: {
          connect: { id: userId },
        },
      },
    })
  );
  return newCourse;
};
```