# Typescript - Can i set the return type of a function dynamically?

Tags: typescript, interface

Is possible to make the variable baz dynamically has the string type?

```
type exampleType = () => ReturnType<exampleType>; // I need to return the type of any function I pass (Eg. ReturnType<typeof foo>)

interface IExampleInterface {
  bar: exampleType;
}

function foo(): string {
  return 'AAAAAAA';
}
const foobar = {
  bar: foo,
} as IExampleInterface;

const baz = foobar.bar();

baz; // Baz has type "any"
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ? The "as" keyword is a type assertion. It tells the compiler to consider the object as another type than the type the compiler infers the object to be. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55781571/4693209
Try to declare your const foobar like this may be: `const foobar: IExampleInterface = {...} `

Answer (score 2):

Not clear to me what the goal of the interface is supposed to be. This is the closest i can get it to what i think you want:

```
interface IExampleInterface<T extends () => any> {
  bar: () => ReturnType<T>;
}

function foo(): string {
  return 'AAAAAAA';
}
const foobar: IExampleInterface<typeof foo> = {
  bar: foo,
}

const baz = foobar.bar();
```

If inferring generics were an option, the `typeof foo` would be superfluous.

Comment: This is the correct answer because OP is asking for the interface to be dependent on the function type. But IMO the code reads much clearer if the generic T refers to the return type rather than the function type.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying too hard. TypeScript features something called type inference which will do this for you for free. Drop the `as IExampleInterface` and it should "just work"

```js
function foo(): string {
  return 'AAAAAAA';
}
const foobar = {
  bar: foo,
}

const baz = foobar.bar();

baz; // Baz has type "string"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is sample code, so maybe the object will have to be passed around and somewhere an argument will have to be typed using the interface and the inferred type will be lost. (It should be fairly obvious that one can drop the interface here)

Comment: based on how new the account is and the way the phrase they question I think this person is new to TypeScript. While you're right, I feel like this answer honestly might be closer to what they were looking for.