# TypeScript: Typing array / tuple with values or empty

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

I'm trying to type a custom React hook:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

type Reference = [
  Promise<unknown>,
  (value?: unknown) => void,
  (reason?: unknown) => void,
];

const usePromise = () => {
  const reference: Reference = [];
  const container = useRef(reference);

  reference[0] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reference[1] = resolve;
    reference[2] = reject;
  });

  // [promise, resolve, reject]
  return container.current;
};

export default usePromise;
```

TypeScript complains about `reference` saying:

```
Type '[]' is not assignable to type 'Reference'.
  Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 3.
```

How can I allow TypeScript to accept the empty array / tuple initialization, too? And also maybe there is a way to give `usePromise` the type of the value, too, so that it doesn't say `unknown`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

If you want to initialize the tuple to an empty array, you can do this:

```
const reference : [Reference, Reference, Reference] = ([] as unknown) as [Reference, Reference, Reference];
```

**Edit: edited as per OP's comment**

You need to do something like this if you want to use a tuple:
Please read the inline comments below.

```
type Reference = {
    name:  string;
    age: number;
}

//In your case, it should be something like this beause your tuple may have upto 3 values of type Reference.

//initialization
//null! - the '!' mark after null is the non-null assertion operator, which will let you assign null value to a type Reference.
const reference2: [Reference, Reference, Reference] = [null!, null!, null!];
//assignment
reference2[0] = {name: 'John', age:10};
```

**Original Answer:**
That is because you have declared a const variable `reference` which is of type `Reference` (object instance of a class, type or interface called `Reference`) and but initializing it with an empty array `[ ]`.

If you want `reference` to have an array of `Reference` objects, then you should do this instead:

```
const reference: Reference[] = [];
```

If you have strict type checking enabled in your tsconfig, you should do it like this:

```
const reference: Reference[] = [] as Reference[];
```

You can read about the `as` keyword here: [Stack Overflow question about the 'as' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do)

Comment: Thank you Link! It is not an array of `References` though. It is either a tuple (triple) with the 3 values, or an empty array. If I cast it like this: `[] as Reference`, I get the error `Conversion of type '[]' to type 'Reference' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 3.`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: So `const reference = ([] as unknown) as Reference;` worked. I don't know though, if that's the best way to handle this.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you please try the solution I suggested. And please try it without using `as Reference` if it doesn't throw you an error for it.

Comment: Thank you Link. The types you suggest unfortunately aren't correct for my instance. (It is not an array of three references. The reference type is a tuple of three values or an empty array.

Comment: Yes, in my answer above, I am creating a tuple of 3 values of type Reference. And, in order to assign the value of that tuple to an empty array, you need to do this: `const reference : [Reference, Reference, Reference] = ([] as unknown) as [Reference, Reference, Reference]`

Comment: I have updated my answer to include this. Also, here is the TypeScript documentation for tuples just for reference : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 0):

The type `Reference` is a tuple with three entries. So when you assign to a variable of the type `Reference`, typescript checks if 1) the assigned value is a tuple 2) if the assigned tuple has the desired length 3) if all types of the entries in the tuple match the corresponding types in the `Reference` type.

You assign an empty list, which violates these conditions. If you don't have strict null checks enabled, you can simply assign `const reference: Reference = [null, null, null];`

Answer (score 0):

Instead for forcing typescript to ignore your problem, I feel it's better to describe `reference` as what it really is:

```
let reference: Reference|null = null;
```

Or:

```
type Reference = [
  Promise<unknown> | null,
  ((value?: unknown) => void) | null,
  ((reason?: unknown) => void) | null,
];
```

Comment: This throws the same error as in my question.