# Typescript did not show error even I did not implement all the compulsory properties of an interface

Tags: typescript, interface, typing

```
interface Test {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

const obj = {
    foo: 'ok'
} as Test;
```

Typescript compiler did not prompt me error even I did not implement `bar` in `obj`. I expect error will be shown at above example, since `bar` is not an optional property. May I know how come? Thanks in advance. At the same time, the following demo makes me confuse as well. `obj` implemented only `Test`, which means it should contain only `foo` and `bar`. However, when I added `zar` in addition, no error is prompt too.

```
interface Test {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

const obj = {
    foo: 'ok',
    bar: 'ok',
    zar: 'expected not ok'
} as Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

please check out this guys answer on what `as` does [What does the "as" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do).

So the as keyword tells the compiler to treat it as your type through enforcement so instead try doing this below:

```
interface Test {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

const obj: Test = {
    foo: 'ok'
};
```