# What are Hooks in JavaScript and how are they used for by by JavaScript testing frameworks like Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, keyword, assertion

I was reading about the [Node.js Assertion Class](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/assert.html#assert_strict_assertion_mode) when I was blown back from what I saw -- there was an `as` operator inside of an `import` statements destructor-brackets! This surprised for couple of reasons:

1. For one, I had thought, previously, that the keyword `as` was a **TypeScript** reserved word only, and had nothing to do with **JavaScript** or **Node.js**, and I am not alone on this. I DuckDuckGo'd the `as` keyword before authoring this question and got the following StackOverflow question as one of the search results:

- [What does the “as” keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do)

Everyone who answered the question above all stated the same thing, "The keyword `as` is a TypeScript thing". It seems that `as` being part of Node.js is not very well known yet.

2. The other reason I was surprised, which leads into my question, had to do with where the `as` keyword was located, inside of an **`import`** statements destructor-brackets, as seen below:

(If you haven't viewed the Node.js link above, you can skip it, below is the use of `as` that I keep referring to.)

```
import { strict as assert } from 'assert';

import assert from 'assert/strict';
```

So what I would like to know is how does the `as` keyword work in Node.JS? Is it going to have use cases outside of assertions, or is the import statement above a singular use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` keyword is a part of ES6 module syntax.

You use `as` when you need to rename the exported named variables/functions in order to avoid conflict between library and your code, or just because you want to rename it XD

You can read more about it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias

Comment: So its a JavaScript thing then? I knew it was used to rename, but I thought it was only used for testing, and I was under the impression that it was only available in typescript. Anywho, now I know...