# ESLint throws `no-redeclare` error for global variable with a single declaration

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have defined a writable global variable, `AS`, in .eslintrc.

`AS` is only declared once in the codebase.

ESLint is throwing the following `no-redeclare` error for the single declaration of the global variable:

`Error - 'AS' is already defined as a built-in global variable. (no-redeclare)`

Why is ESLint throwing a `no-redeclare` error when the variable is only declared once?

Is there a way to disable this automatically instead of manually disabling the line in the source file?

Comment: Eslint doesn't know the declaration you're linting *is* the one global declaration. It only knows there already is a global of that name (because you told it so), and assumes that your declaration collides with that.

Comment: Look here: [Disallow Redeclaring Variables (no-redeclare)](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-redeclare)

Comment: Maybe the `AS` comes from some TypeScript? [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - the ESLint docs you linked to don't seem to answer my question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, nope, no TypeScript.

Comment: The error means the `AS` is already declared somewhere for sure.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it _is_ declared somewhere indeed. The error message points to the line in the file where the var is declared. That line is also the only line where the var is declared.

Comment: *`as` is contextual keyword in JavaScript - when the code runs into the syntax rule ImportClause* [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68674619/2159528)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The OP's error message is about `AS`, not about `as` - and even a variable named `as` is totally valid.

Comment: Eslint `no-declare` provide the `builtinGlobals` option to ignore the global variable.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare#builtinglobals

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, after you defined AS in ESLint as a global variable it considers it already defined so when it encounters
`var AS = ...` or `function AS() {}` in your code it complains about this with
[no-redeclare](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-redeclare)

The solution (workaround) I found to this problem - in a browser environment - was to declare the variable (in my case it was a function) attached to the `window` object.

```
window.AS = ...
```

That will not be considered a re-declaration by ESLint v8.21.0.