# JSX Operator precedence ?: and?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operator-precedence

I m working with React-Router-v6 and i want to pass some props as location in `useRoutes()`. I m a little bit confused because i find an example [Modal](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/modal?file=src/App.tsx) although this example doesn't use `useRoutes()` i was trying to run it but some operators throws some errors when i run it.
I find the `?:` as [conditional operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operator_precedence)
but i cannot find how it works. It looks like something as `... ? ... : ...` but this doesn't work for me.

My whole question is how the command below works and what the following operators (`as` and `?:`) do.

```
let state = useLocation().state as { backgroundLocation?: Location };
```

PS: I think that the whole command is something like assign the `Location` as new property of `state` with name `backgroundLocation` but i still don't comprehend the whole functionality.

Comment: `?:` isn't an operator in what you've posted, that's **TypeScript**. The errors are presumably because you're treating it like it's JavaScript.

Comment: If you notice at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operator_precedence) `?:` refers as an operator. Thks.

Comment: Right, but that's for JavaScript and, again, _you have TypeScript_. Everything from `as` onwards is **not** JavaScript, and would be erased in compilation. Note that what you've linked to is a `.tsx` file.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55781559/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe you 're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a TypeScript [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). It's unrelated to the conditional operator.

`as` tells TypeScript "ignore what you compute the type to be, and instead assume it's the type I tell you". `{ backgroundLocation?: Location }` means an object with an optional property backgroundLocation. The value of backgroundLocation is either `undefined` (thanks to being optional) or a `Location`.

If your project is not set up to transpile typescript, then you'll need to remove the typescript and just do plain javascript. To do so for this code, simply delete `as { backgroundLocation?: Location }`

Comment: as tells TypeScript "ignore what you compute the type to be, and instead assume it's the type I tell you" -> that's not entirely true. This line wouldn't work: const test = "hello" as boolean because neither type overlaps with the other.

Comment: @jperl it's true that typescript will metaphorically ask "are you sure?" if you make a really egregious assertion, to which you can respond "yes, i'm sure" via `as unknown as boolean`.