# Can someone explain to me what does 'as never' do in this piece of code?

Tags: typescript

Like the title says, I'm confused as to what 'as never' means in this piece of code. I read that it's supposed to mean something that never occurs or excludes other types but I'm not quite grasping why it's being used the way it is in the piece of code below.

```
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Google Search',
    screen: 'MapScreen',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'I\'m Feeling Lucky',
    screen: 'MapScreen',
  }
]

const NavOptions = (props: NavProps) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      horizontal
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => props.term && navigation.navigate(item.screen as never, {
              term: props.term,
            } as never)}
            style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "#f8f9fa",
    padding: 10,
  },
  text: {
    color: "black",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

type NavProps = {
  term: string;
}

export default NavOptions
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "as" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do)

Comment: From the link above: *"The `as` keyword is a Type Assertion in TypeScript which tells the compiler to consider the object as another type than the type the compiler infers the object to be."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey no I understand that 'as' is for type assertion in typescript. What I don't understand is why we put 'as never' in the piece of code above.

Comment: It looks like nonsense. This code is wrong.

Comment: I believe this cannot ever be right, and looks like a mistake. Maybe because someone could not get the type right and used `never` instead of `any`, for undecipherable reasons.

Comment: @Mathieu This code is from a project that handles navigation. When I run the project in vscode, everything works and I don't get an errors from Typescript or in the functionality and I can't understand why haha

Comment: Please post the full source, or wider context, then. I cannot understand this typing either. I assume `useNavigation` is from this library https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#navigate. `as` is used to coerce a type against TS's assumptions, and there is no reason I can find in this context.

Comment: @Mathieu I think this is answerable as it is already. No need to post full code.

Comment: @Mathieu I just edited and added the full source code. This is supposed to be a component that generates the google buttons and navigate to the proper screen

Comment: There is still no reason for the use of `as never` that I can see, and they can / should probably be deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is simply wrong.

Your understanding of `never` is roughly correct: it is a type with no valid values and it often arises as intersection of incompatible types; it represents unreachable code, situations that are logically impossible and expressions that cannot be fully evaluated.  A typical example is functions that throw instead of returning normally:

```ts
function raiseRangeErr(e: string): never {
    throw new RangeError(e);
}

function div(a: number, b: number): number {
    return b !== 0 ? a / b : raiseRangeErr("division by zero");
}
```

`never` has the unique property that expressions of this type are assignable to any other type.  This works, because since `never` has no values, in particular it has no values that may fail to be members of the target type.

The programmer who wrote that code probably wanted to lazily take advantage of this property to suppress errors about unassignable types.  From a type theory perspective, this is incorrect: code which has `never` in scope is supposed to be unreachable, yet the code in the question is clearly anything but.

Type assertions are best avoided anyway; if you can simply remove those assertions and not get any errors, do that.  If you have to use a type assertion after all, use a type specific to the situation at hand.  In the worst case, use `as any`.  The only situation in which `as never` would be remotely acceptable is when calling a function that you happen to know never returns, but you lack type definitions that capture that.  For a contrived example:

```ts
function raiseRangeErr(e: string): unknown {
    throw new RangeError(e);
}

function div(a: number, b: number): number {
    return b !== 0 ? a / b : raiseRangeErr("division by zero") as never;
}
```

Even then, it would be preferable to update your type definitions.