# How to set css variable using react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

how to set css variable in react typescript
if I'm trying to

```
 <main style={{ "--nav-height": navHeight }}>
  </main>
main {
  height: calc(100vh -var(--nav-height));
  background: green;
}
```

I'm getting

```
Type '{ "--nav-height": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
```

Answer (score 3):

In TypeScript, React's `style` property types are mapped to actual CSS properties (`minHeight` => `min-height`, etc).

Since you are entering an unknown property, it fails the type check.

What you can do is assert the type yourself so this doesn't happen anymore.

### Method 1

You can set the *property name* to be `any`, thus skipping this property when checked:

```
<main style={{ ["--nav-height" as any]: navHeight }}>
```

### Method 2

You can cast the *entire object* so it always fits (**not recommended** - this might cause problems with other properties' types as they might stop working and auto completing for you)

```
<main style={{ "--nav-height": navHeight } as React.CSSProperties}>
```

Comment: Both methods produce eslint error. Method-1 **@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any**; Method-2 **@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions**

Comment: You can read what `as` operation does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55781571/721809) and why it doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that you are using an invalid property for the `style` prop. Perhaps you are confusing `--nav-height` with `height`.

You can try the following:

```
<main style={{ height: "var(--nav-height)" }}></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is not related to Typescript. You have this error because when you declare a `style` props, TS is waiting for valid properties like `color`, `backgroundColor`, etc... which your  `--nav-height` is not.

To set the value of a CSS variable using JavaScript (and so, React, since it's just Javacsript), you use `setProperty` on documentElement's style property:

You have to do somehting like this :

```
    const createVariable = () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--my-color', 'pink');
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1 onClick={createVariable}>Click me to set the variable!</h1>
            <p style={{color: "var(--my-color)"}}>Look at me !</p>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set or to use a CSS variable into a JS context you could use a dedicated util function.

**The util function to **set** it :**

```
export const jsAsCSS = (name: string, value: string) => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, value);
}
```

**The usage of the setter :**

```
  const HelloWorld = () => {
  
  const setCSSVariable = () => {
    Utils.jsAsCSS("--my-color", "red");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setCSSVariable}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

**The util function to **use** it :**

```
export const cssAsJS = (name: string) =>
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(name);
```

**The usage of the user :**

```
const myColor = cssAsJS("--color-red");
```