# What does the `as` keyword actually do inside a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

I am a novice in typescript, The following example of `as` confuses me.

```js
type foo = "a" | "b" | 1 | 2;
type bar = {
    [k in foo as number]: any
}
```

The example is type checked. and `bar` type is translated into

```js
type bar = {
    [x: number]: any
}
```

why `k in foo as number` can be translated into `x: number`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "as" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do)

Comment: @Tomerikoo no it doesn't. That's a different use of the word "as". See the answer from jcalz below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using [*key remapping in mapped types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  This is *not* a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  Both key remapping and type assertions can use the `as` keyword, but they are for quite different purposes; it is almost coincidental that they use the same keyword.

A normal non-remapped [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) is of the form `{[T in KK]: V<T>}` which defines a type parameter `T` that iterates over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members of the keylike type `KK` (which must be a subtype of `PropertyKey`, a.k.a. `string | number | symbol`), and then for each of these union members `T`, the output has a property with key `T` and value `V<T>` (where `V` is some type function, like `type V<T> = {x: T}`).  So the value type can be any function of the type parameter `T`, but the key type is restricted to be just `T` itself.  (Because the type parameter is required to be keylike, the name of the type parameter often reflects that by being something like `K` for Key, or `P` for Property.) This is very useful, but sometimes people want to compute the keys as well as the values.

Key remapping lets you have the type parameter iterate over *any* union whatsoever, (not just keylike types), and then you compute the keys and the values from that type parameter.  It's of the form `{[T in U as K<T>]: V<T>}` which defines a type parameter `T` that iterates over the union members of the type `U`, and then for each of these union members `T`, the output has a property with key `K<T>` (which must be a keylike type function, like `` type K<T extends string> = `key_${T}` ``) and value `V<T>`.

Your example

```
type Foo = "a" | "b" | 1 | 2;
type Bar = {
  [K in Foo as number]: any
}
```

is a [degenerate case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)), since you are iterating over `Foo` but completely ignoring it when computing the key type.  Instead, the key type is `number`, no matter what `K` is.  So the output will have a single `number` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) with value type `any`.

If you wanted a slightly more realistic example, you could compute the key as a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) that depends on `K`, like this:

```
type Baz = {
  [K in Foo as `key_${K}`]: any
}
/* type Baz = {
    key_a: any;
    key_b: any;
    key_1: any;
    key_2: any;
} */
```

And if you want an example where you iterate over a non-key type, it could look like this:

```
type KVPair = { k: "a", v: string } | { k: "b", v: number } | { k: "c", v: boolean };
type Qux = { [T in KVPair as T["k"]]: T["v"] };
/* type Qux = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
} */
```

This is quite a powerful feature, which again, has essentially nothing to do with type assertions.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiAhqqAfNAjLXARhygCYBuAWAChRIoAhdAJ2SgG9aooBtAaSgBLAHawEUdAGcoIgK4BbPBBYBdAFySRIWgF9atAPQAqKPWjM2KLjR49eAD03ylKjVpDUauqMcMG6cAt0AC92G3tBUXFEaSgAAwBrCBAAfQASDn5dePd0bT0jU3MmUPDuO2S09E18zwqeKtS8Wu0vOygmolb620qU1LIerx8-AJL+ADUABXQhK05OzQxUABooADdNKWAWUQBzKB9cDiX8Nc3nRWU2Y8XE5YBjC62oPAQAGwh8o68SgEU5A5wnwACrCMRTWbzSQyUG8VCJVCqdzw1AbZG-IpmIJQQHA6wNSTbXYHdp2Fqya4qck8R6ad5wL75Ea+QxAA)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's a lot more comprehensive than the brief explanation in the official TypeScript documentation that you linked above, which left me scratching my head and googling until I found your explanation!