# How to delete property from nested objects inside interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following sample

```
interface DataProvider {
    type: string;
    // other props
}

interface ApiConfiguration {
    dataProvider: DataProvider;
    // other props
}

interface Configuration {
    api: ApiConfiguration;
    // other props
}

const configuration: Configuration = {
    api: {
        dataProvider: { type: 'http' }
    }
};
```

This configuration will be validated against a schema. For a given test I want to ensure a validation error will be thrown if the `type` field is missing.

```
delete configuration.api.dataProvider.type
```

is not possible because

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.

since the interface must have the `type` prop. I am aware that there are Pick and Omit, but creating a custom interface type for each test case would be very time-consuming.

Currently I'm using this approach

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
const clonedConfiguration: any = structuredClone(configuration);

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const {type: _, ...dataProviderWithoutType} = clonedConfiguration.api.dataProvider;

clonedConfiguration.api.dataProvider = dataProviderWithoutType;
```

but is there a more elegant way to remove props from nested children?

Comment: I think the correct way would be to use omit.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler but then I would have to create a whole new configuration type with all subtypes .. no?

Comment: If you want to write a *test* where you want to pass something to your validation function that is not a `Configuration`, don't declare that object as a `Configuration`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small utility to omit the type property in your nested type.

```
type ChangeFields<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;

type TestConfig = ChangeFields<Configuration, {
    api: ChangeFields<ApiConfiguration, {
        dataProvider: ChangeFields<DataProvider, {
            type?: string
        }>
    }>
}>

const withoutType = (obj: Configuration): TestConfig  => {
    const res = obj as TestConfig; //deepclone if used elsewhere
    delete res.api.dataProvider.type;
    return res;
}

const c = withoutType(configuration);
```

As you only need this to write a test it probably won't be an issue, but you should properly deepclone the object when you're deleting a nested property if it's referenced in other places. Otherwise you would modify a differently typed object through the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` keyword from Typescript to do this. When using it, you explicitly tell Typescript not to worry about what's inside the object.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/what-does-the-as-keyword-do) for details.

```js
interface DataProvider {
    type: string;
    // other props
}

interface ApiConfiguration {
    dataProvider: DataProvider;
    // other props
}

interface Configuration {
    api: ApiConfiguration;
    // other props
}

const configuration: Configuration = {
    api: {
        dataProvider: {} as DataProvider,
    }
};
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but better not declare that object as a `Configuration` when it isn't one.

Comment: @Bergi In the "runtime" or "application" code indeed, this is not a good practice. However OP is writing a test in which they explicitly want to simulate wrong typed data. In my opinion, declaring here `{}` as a `Configuration` is appropriate.

Comment: @clementlize I disagree. I think that the types of the validation function the OP wants to call should explicitly reflect that it may be called with invalid data.

Comment: I downvoted because it's not a clean solution. It covers up the fact, that type is optional. It's a workaround not a solution.