# Why are types not enforced when using type cast in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm new to typescript and trying to learn it. I want to initialise an object of a class from a simple object of type `any`. However the types are not forced.

Here is the code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { IsDefined, IsNumber, IsString, validate } from 'class-validator';

export class Test {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNumber()
  public foo: number;

  @IsString()
  public bar?: string;

  constructor(foo: number, bar?: string) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

const x: any = {
  bar: 'Hello World',
};

const t: Test = x as Test; // <- Was expecting code to crash here

validate(t).then((errors) => {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    console.log(errors);
  }
});

console.log(t);
console.log(t.foo);
```

Created a gist on [StackBlitz](https://typescript-dvfzxa.stackblitz.io). Also created a test [repo](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/typescript-type-enforce):

I was expecting my code to crash, since foo is required but it is not available when I do `x as Test`.

Does casting x into Test not do a type check?

Comment: `Does casting x into Test not do a type check?` correct. It's purely a compile-time operation, to tell the type checker "don't worry if you can't prove it, I'm _sure_ `x` is a `Test`".

Comment: Checkout https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typescript-duck-typing/.

Comment: TypeScript has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), not "casts".  Or rather, the term "cast" is too ambiguous to be useful and is best avoided.  See the answers to the linked questions for more information

Comment: See also this StackOverlflow question: [What does the "as" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781559/)

Comment: @yshavit I see, even the `as` keyword doesn't do any type checking and is purely for compilation. My understanding was it will create a new object for it, but as @MarkSwardstrom mentioned I should use duck-typing.